# There was an error in serializing body of message

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to give a datatable to my WCF for it to be accessed by other clients. I seem to get the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: There was an error in serializing body of
>   message givePersonRequest: 'There was an error generating the XML
>   document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

The InnerException is.

{"There was an error generating the XML document."}

My service code is this.

```
 [OperationContract]
    bool givePerson(DataTable per, int id);
```

Which corresponds with.

```
   public bool givePerson(DataTable per, int id)
    {
        DataRow[] temp = ((DataTable)per).Select();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].id == id)
            {
                data[i].addPerson(temp);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: And where you create/parse the XML? I don't see it anywhere. Also, do you know the line that is throwing that error?

Comment: See inner of inner exception

Comment: the line throwing the error is   return base.Channel.givePerson(request); From my refernce.cs

Comment: Before getting this error I wasn't aware I was creating a xml and can't locate it

Comment: the XML is created by WCF. its how it communicated data iirc. Is DataTable also a DataContract?

Comment: [Enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) to see more details. Maybe you missing knownTypes or something.

Comment: Also try to set data table name saw its matters :)

Comment: @Reniuz thank you i had comment out the table name

Comment: @Reniuz Please post your answer, so I can mark it as correct as it was the table names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in serializing body of message : 'There was an error generating the XML document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
This issue on application side by using the webservice below

```
    public int InsPatientLanguages(DataTable dt)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        int val = 0;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblPatLanguages", dt);

        val = DAC.SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.Ins_PatLanguages");
       return val;
    }
```